# Getting error sound without including any?

Tags: c++, audio

I'm following a book and currently learning about pointers and such however when i run this code i also get a wierd error sound. It's kinda cool that it does but i don't know why it's called and the book didn't say anything about (possibly cause the book is decently old now). The sound occurs when i call for 'ErrorMessage'. Is that some kind of easter egg cause i don't remember including any audio libaries?

```
#include <iostream>

ErrorMessage(char* msg)
{
    std::cout << "\aError:" << msg << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    char* ep = "Invalid Input";

    ErrorMessage(ep);

    char msg[] = "Disk Failure";

    ErrorMessage(msg);

    ErrorMessage("Timeout");
}
```

Comment: Troll program 101: `while(true) std::cout << '\a';`

Comment: @PasserBy: Yup that's one of those things we used to do at PC world in the early 1990s, before Windows 95 ruined everything with login prompts.

Answer (score 3):

Its because of

```
 std::cout << "\aError:" << msg << std::endl;
```

Notice that `\a`.
`\a` is an escape character which is audible alert which is generating that sound

Answer (score 2):

You have used an *escape* sequence when you've typed that backslash in your `std::cout` literal.

`\a` is a very old-fashioned way of sending a beep signal to your terminal (called the BEL character), assuming your console (i.e. the thing that you used to launch your application) supports beeping.

Answer (score 2):

`\a` is the [control character for a bell sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character), so printing it to `std::cout` will produce one; exactly what `ErrorMessage()` does:

```
std::cout << "\aError:" << msg << std::endl; // make a beep then print "Error: <msg>"
```

Answer (score 2):

`\a` (the `a` stands for `alert`)is the encoding for the ASCII BEL character, which will cause the terminal bell to be rung when it is  output, assuming your terminal software or hardware supports such functionality.